c# Converting Nested JSON that may contain No, One or Multiple objects
I'm writing a an Azure Function App in PowerShell to manage Exchange Online User's Mailbox settings. (no Not available vs MS Graph)
I'm looking to see what Members of a Group there are. When I issue the Command
$getDistListOutput = Get-DistributionGroupMember  @getDistListparms |   Where-Object {$_.alias -ne $SelfIdentity} | Select-Object Identity 

I can get one of three types of results in $getDistListOutput, Null, One user or Multiple users. When I take the output $getDistListOutput and convert it to JSON and add to the Existing JSON structure I get one of the three situations:
//No GroupMember
{
  "ForwardingAddressID": "{\"Identity\":\"smtp:nivek@domain.com\"}",
  "GroupMembers": null
}

//Single GroupMember
{
  "ForwardingAddressID": "{\"Identity\":\"smtp:nivek@domain.com\"}",
  "GroupMembers": "{\"Identity\":\"smtp:nivek@domain.com\"}",
}

//Multiple GroupMembers
{
  "ForwardingAddressID": "{\"Identity\":\"smtp:nivek@domain.com\"}",
  "GroupMembers": ["{\"Identity\":\"smtp:nivek2@domain.com\"}","{\"Identity\":\"smtp:nivek@domain.com\"}"]
}

No I'm trying to map the data returned into C# Classes. The following works for the ForwardingAddressID though I can't seem to come up with the proper way to get the GroupMembers decoded with its 3 variants.
           ExchPS_GetUserMailData_Reply getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchPS_GetUserMailData_Reply>(AzureResponseDeserialized.OutputData);
                
           if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.ForwardingAddressID)))
           {
               ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data forwardingAddressIDSerializedReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data>(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.ForwardingAddressID);

               if ((forwardingAddressIDSerializedReply != null) )
               {
                   if (forwardingAddressIDSerializedReply.Identity != null)
                   {
                       ForwardMbx = true;
                       ForwardMbxTo = forwardingAddressIDSerializedReply.Identity;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       ForwardMbx = false;
                       ForwardMbxTo = "";
                   }
               }

           }

If there is nothing in the value set for GroupMembers, don't do anything.
If there is a [ as the First, it's an Array.
If there is a { as the First, it's a single.
if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers)))
{
    if (getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers[0] == '[')
    {
        ExchPS_GroupMembers_Reply[] getGroupMembersSerializedReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchPS_GroupMembers_Reply[]>(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers);
        if ((getGroupMembersSerializedReply != null))
        {
            if (getGroupMembersSerializedReply.First != null)
            {
                ForwardMbx = true;
                //ForwardMbxTo = getGroupMembersSerializedReply.Identity[0].Identity;
            }
            else
            {
                ForwardMbx = false;
            }
        } 
    } else if (getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers[0] == '{')
    {
        ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data getGroupMembersSerializedReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data>(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers);
        if (getGroupMembersSerializedReply != null)
        {
            if (getGroupMembersSerializedReply.Identity != null)
            {
                ForwardMbx = true;
                ForwardMbxTo = getGroupMembersSerializedReply.Identity;
            }
            else
            {
                ForwardMbx = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

Classes defined:
// Single User Identity
class ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Identity))]
    public string Identity { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

// Array of User Identities
[JsonArray]
class ExchPS_GroupMembers_Reply
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Identity))]
    public string Identity { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}


class ExchPS_GetUserMailData_Reply
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(GroupMembers))]
    public string GroupMembers { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty(nameof(ForwardingAddressID))]
    public string ForwardingAddressID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}


I would probably go along the route of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859490/parsing-both-array-and-single-object
and not deal with trying to parse it separately and also json parse it, just do it in one step.
If not desired or some other technical reason, it would probably easier to use powershell to format it into a list always, but I would probably go with the prior.

If you control serialization, is there any reason you can't just make GroupMembers an array in all 3 cases - $null becomes an empty array, a single object becomes an array with one item, and multiple objects become an array with multiple items. Deserialization will always result in an array then, and you just check the length... A simple way would be to wrap your existing expression in @( ... ) - i.e. $getDistListOutput = @( Get-DistributionGroupMember  @getDistListparms | Where-Object {$_.alias -ne $SelfIdentity} | Select-Object Identity  )

They're all wrong because you have double-serialization: a JSON object inside a JSON string inside a JSON object.

I agree with @mclayton, I even suspect that you source is always an array (please share more of the orginal json file) as PowerShell often unexpectedly automatically unrolls an array. Please try to build an [mcve] of what you actually try to achieve.

See How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net (for converter(s) to handle the case where a property might be a single object or an array of the same) and How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object? (for a converter that handles your double-serialized JSON objects).  Do those two questions answer yours?

So on the PowerShell JSON Creation side, I added the -AsArray to the ConvertTo-Json for the hash table.  This allowed the cases of One or >One to all be of type Array(List)
    $getDistListOutput = Get-DistributionGroupMember  @getDistListparms |   Where-Object {$_.alias -ne $DLIdentity} | Select-Object Identity  

$PSCmdOutput = @{
    ForwardingAddressID = $getForwardingAddressIDOutput | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 10 
    GroupMembers = $getDistListOutput | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray -Compress -Depth 10 
    AutoReplyConfig = $getMbcAutoReplytConfigOutput | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 10
}

On the C# receiving side. I made the GroupMembers class a [JsonArray], made the member of type List<ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data>
// Single User Identity
class ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(Identity))]
    public string Identity { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

// Array of User Identities
[JsonArray]
class ExchPS_GroupMembers_Reply
{
    [JsonProperty(nameof(GroupMembers))]
    public List<ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data>? GroupMembers { get; set; } 
}

//Reply from Azure Function
class AzureReply
{   
 [JsonProperty("OutputData")]
 public string OutputData { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 [JsonProperty("PSCommandOutput")]
 public string PSCommandOutput { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 [JsonProperty("Error")]
 public string Error { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 [JsonProperty("Exception")]
 public string Exception { get; set; } = string.Empty;

 }

The code to get the data out of the returned JSON member.
 //Get the reply from Azure and get the members
 AzureReply AzureResponseDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureReply>(AzureResponse);

 [...snip...]

 //Get the OutputData member
ExchPS_GetUserMailData_Reply getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchPS_GetUserMailData_Reply>(AzureResponseDeserialized.OutputData);


//If the GroupMembers is NULL we didn't get a member
if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers)))
{
                       
    List<ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data> getGroupMembersDeserializedReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data>>(getUserMailDataReplyDeserialized.GroupMembers);
    if ((getGroupMembersDEserializedReply != null))
    {
        //Just deal with the First Member at this point. 
        ExchPS_UserIdentity_Data firstgroupmember = getGroupMembersDeserializedReply.First();

        if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstgroupmember.Identity)))
        {
            ForwardSendAs = true;
            ForwardSendAs1 = true;

            ForwardTo = firstgroupmember.Identity;
                                
        }
        else
        {
            ForwardSendAs = false;
        }
    } 
                        
}

