# Dynamic filtering critieria for post query

Tags: java, json, data-structures, dynamic, enumeration

I need a dynamic filtering criteria for querying west webservices using post.

to give you an example.

```
{
  "fields": [
             "field":"firstName",
             "field":"lastName"
            ]
,
  "filters": 
           [
              filter{"field":"firstName",
                     "operation":"EQ",
                     "value":"FIRSTNAME"
                    },
              filter{"field":"LastName",
                     "operation":"LIKE",
                     "value":["FIRSTNAME"]
                    },
              filter{"field":"address",
                     "operation":"IN",
                     "value":["1","2","3","4"]
                    },
           ]
}
```

please observe for operation "EQ" , it has single string, for rest of the filters, you need a list

based on operation, i want the value to be either as List or single string, how to build this dynamically in java, is it possible.

Comment: "single string" what do you mean by that?

Comment: please observe for operation "EQ" , it has single string, for rest of the filters, you need a list

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but don't do this, ever ([example solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412261/make-gson-accept-single-objects-where-it-expects-arrays/43412985#43412985)).

Instead, design your input in a clear way, so the user knows that there is option to put multiple values there. Maybe name a field `values` or `valueList`?

Don't create custom adapters, factory registries or custom deserializers, just redesign. Also don't go in the opposite direction - that would be accepting a list even with `EQ` parameter where you only need one element, just to simplify model. It's easier to code, but the end user is confused.

Answer (score 0):

Got my own solution had a abstract class as filter , then added two filters classes for list and not list separately , works wonderfully