# Gson handle integer or array of integers

Tags: java, gson

I have JSON that may look like this

```
  {
     "endpoint": {
         "status": "xxxx",
         "port": [ 123 ],
     }
  }
```

or this

```
{
     "endpoint": {
         "status": "xxxxxxx",
         "port": 456,
     }
}
```

I have class

```
public class Endpoint {
    private String status;
    private List<Integer> port;
}
```

in my code

```
    Endpoint endpoint = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Endpoint.class);
```

I got error like so:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER
```

I know the problem with de-serialization that **port** field's type is either returned as Integer or List of Integer, which I have no control over and have to consume as is.

How to properly de-serialize using Gson in this situation? is custom de-serialization way to go? if so I'd appreciate if someone can give an example. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412261/make-gson-accept-single-objects-where-it-expects-arrays/43412985#43412985

Comment: @BlackPearl that got the problem solved Thanks!