# Json string to Object mapping with dynamic values

Tags: java, gson, mapping, unmarshalling, jsonobjectrequest

I am consuming Thirdparty jsonString, I am trying to parse the json but sometimes JSON object "RadarReports" is an list and sometimes it object.

```
{"RadarReports": {
    "executionTime": "135",
"RadarReport": {
        "abc": "1116591",
        "name": "abc",
        "id": "2019050311582056119",
        "ownerId": "xyz"
    },
"size" :"1"
}}
```

=================

```
  {"RadarReports": {
        "executionTime": "113",
        "RadarReport": [
            {
                 "abc": "1116591",
            "name": "abc",
            "id": "2019050311582056119",
            "ownerId": "xyz"
            },
            {
            "abc": "1116591",
            "name": "abc",
            "id": "2019050311582056119",
            "ownerId": "xyz"
            },
        ]
    "size" : "2"
    }}
```

I tried below to parse but failing when single object came into picture, need to accept both single and list of objects.

```
@Data
public class Radarreports {
    private int size;
    private ArrayList<RadarreportSet> RadarReportSet;
    private ArrayList<RadarReport> RadarReport;
}

@Data
public
class ReportsResponse {
    Radarreports RadarReports;
}

URL url = new URL(queryUrl);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ReportsResponse radarReports = gson.fromJson(br, ReportsResponse.class);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make GSON accept single objects where it expects arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412261/make-gson-accept-single-objects-where-it-expects-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) which creates an adapter which first peeks at the type of the JSON data and then adds special handling where the JSON object is not wrapped in an JSON array:

```java
// Only intended for usage with @JsonAdapter
class SingleObjectOrListAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // Note: Cannot use getDelegateAdapter due to https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1028
        TypeAdapter<T> listAdapterDelegate = gson.getAdapter(type);
        TypeAdapter<JsonObject> jsonObjectAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonObject.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                listAdapterDelegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
                    // Wrap JSON object in a new JSON array before parsing it
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonObjectAdapter.read(in);
                    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
                    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);

                    return listAdapterDelegate.fromJsonTree(jsonArray);
                } else {
                    return listAdapterDelegate.read(in);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The factory can then be specified for the affected field with [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html):

```java
@JsonAdapter(SingleObjectOrListAdapterFactory.class)
private ArrayList<RadarReport> RadarReport;
```