# Java ignore custom deserialization on GSON if json format is valid

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

I have been looking around but could not find any conclusion for my problem, I'll try to describe it the best way I can.

I'm calling an API that can respond 2 ways (***note that class names are only examples, not the real names***):

Bad response:

```
{
        "CustomObject_1" : {
            "CustomObject_1.1" : {
                ...
            },
            "CustomObject_1.2" : [
                [ ]
            ]
        },
        "CustomObject_2" : {
            ...
        }
```

Good response:

```
{
        "CustomObject_1" : {
            "CustomObject_1.1" : {
                ...
            },
            "CustomObject_1.2" : [
                "CustomObject_1.2.1" : {
                ...
                }
            ]
        },
        "CustomObject_2" : {
            ...
        }
```

The difference is in `CustomObject_1.2` that can be a custom object (that contains more layers of custom objects inside), or it can be an empty array.

I have a deserializer that corrects the bad response, but it makes the good response null, instead of using the default serialization.

`class CustomObject_1.2Deserializer`

```
public CustomObject_1.2 deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
            if (jsonArray.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println(jsonArray);  // return an empty Totals object
                return new CustomObject_1.2();
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            if (jsonObject.has("CustomObject_1.2.1") && jsonObject.get("CustomObject_1.2.1").isJsonArray()) {
                JsonArray competitorsArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("competitors");
                System.out.println(competitorsArray);   //valid object so use default serialization
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Is there a way to ignore the deserialization when the json comes as a valid object?

In case it's needed here is the function that handles the gson serialization:

```
private MyDtoInterface processResponse(String message) {
        MyDtoInterface mDto = null;
        try {
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(CustomObject_1.2.class, new CustomObject_1.2Deserializer())
                        .create();
                mDto = gson.fromJson(message, CustomparentDTO.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Json format not compatible with ParentDTO");
        }
        return mDto;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

I've lost count of what I've tried. And most examples I can find use primitives and not CustomObjects inside CustomObjects.

I was trying to only deserialize the invalid json. If I try to build a `new CustomObject_1.2()` it will be endless because it's attributes are not primites like String, Integer, Date, ... they are custom objecst inside objects.

The code above will return the following:
Bad response (will build a good DTO):

```
{
        "CustomObject_1" : {
            "CustomObject_1.1" : {
                ...
            },
            "CustomObject_1.2" : [
                "CustomObject_1.2.1" : null
            ]
        },
        "CustomObject_2" : {
            ...
        }
```

Good response (will build a null DTO):

```
{
        "CustomObject_1" : {
            "CustomObject_1.1" : {
                ...
            },
            "CustomObject_1.2" : [
                All elements are null
            ]
        },
        "CustomObject_2" : {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Did you edit your code before pasting it here? Because as far as I know `CustomObject_1.2` is not a valid Java class name. In general please choose valid class names in your examples (e.g. `CustomObject_1_2`) and make sure they actually compile, or even better that they are [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also it looks like the syntax of the JSON snippets you provided is invalid; `[ ... "CustomObject_1.2.1": ... ]` is not valid. Did you mean `{ "CustomObject_1.2.1": ... }`? Please verify that they are correct. Please also provide the code for your `CustomObject_1` class so that the complete structure of your data is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my deserializer code like below and it looks like it's working like it should, although I'm not sure if it makes sense.

```
public CustomObject_1.2 deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
        JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
        if (jsonArray.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println(jsonArray);  // return an empty Totals object
            return new CustomObject_1.2();
        }
    } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        if (jsonObject.has("CustomObject_1.2.1") && jsonObject.get("CustomObject_1.2.1").isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray competitorsArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("competitors");
            System.out.println(competitorsArray);   //valid object so use default serialization
            return new Gson.fromJson(jsonObject, CustomObject_1.2.class);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is just another question and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43412261) where either a single object or an array of objects should be deserialized. The solution to this is therefore also similar:

You can create a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) whose created adapter peeks at the JSON data. If it finds a JSON array, it expects that the array is empty and returns `new CustomObject_1_2()`; otherwise it delegates deserialization to the actual adapter (if you haven't specified one, Gson defaults to using reflection).

The advantage compared to your code is that it uses `TypeAdapterFactory` and `TypeAdapter` rather than `JsonDeserializer` and is therefore likely more efficient because it directly operates on the JSON data stream, and also it reuses the same `Gson` instance and therefore also considers any custom adapters which you might registered for the types of the fields of `CustomObject_1_2`.

For example:

```java
class CustomObject_1_2_AdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    public static final CustomObject_1_2_AdapterFactory INSTANCE = new CustomObject_1_2_AdapterFactory();

    private CustomObject_1_2_AdapterFactory() { }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // Only handle CustomObject_1_2, let other factories handle all other types
        if (type.getRawType() != CustomObject_1_2.class) {
            return null;
        }

        TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
                    // Expecting an empty JSON array
                    in.beginArray();
                    in.endArray();

                    // Cast is safe because factory checked that type is CustomObject_1_2
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    T t = (T) new CustomObject_1_2();
                    return t;
                } else {
                    return delegate.read(in);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then register it like this:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(CustomObject_1_2_AdapterFactory.INSTANCE)
    .create();
```

If you don't just have to differentiate between whether the data is a JSON array or a JSON object and need additional checks such as for the `CustomObject_1.2.1` property as shown in your code, then it would be more complicated because you would first have to parse the JSON data as `JsonObject` to peek at the fields.