# JSON, data can have object and array and use data class for all

Tags: java, json, gson

When trying to process JSON, I recive **Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

This JSON is a client with array in data but i want to use the same data class for other for example employee, but I need that data can store different classes

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "client": "PAL",
            "organization": "*",
            "organization_info": {
                "name": "*",
                "searchKey": "0",
                "id": "0"
            },
            "id": "*****",
            "searchKey": "AJ23",
            "commercialName": "MANOLO",
            "fiscalName": "MANOLO",
            "locations": [{
                    "address": "NUEVA",
                    "city": "SEVILLA",
                    "zipCode": "00000",
                    "country": "ES"}]
        },
        {
            "client": "LAC",
            "organization": "*",
            "organization_info": {
                "name": "*",
                "searchKey": "0",
                "id": "0"
            },
            "id": "*****",
            "searchKey": "0ASD13",
            "commercialName": "DANI",
            "fiscalName": "DANI",
            "locations": [{
                    "address": "FONTANA",
                    "city": "VALLADOLID",
                    "zipCode": "00000",
                    "country": "ES"
                }]
        }]
}
```

This JSON has a data object since it only has one result

```json
{
    "data": {
        "client": "PAL",
            "organization": "*",
            "organization_info": {
                "name": "*",
                "searchKey": "0",
                "id": "0"
            },
            "id": "*****",
            "searchKey": "AJ2",
            "commercialName": "MANOLO",
            "fiscalName": "MANOLO",
            "locations": [
                    "address": "NUEVA",
                    "city": "SEVILLA",
                    "zipCode": "00000",
                    "country": "ES"
             }]
       }
}
```

The idea of the Data class is that it be generic to be able to call different classes Customer, Provider, etc. from the main class.

```java
public class Data<T> {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private final List<T> data;
    String links;

    public Data(List<T> data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    //get and set method
```

```java
public class Client {
    private String client;
    private String organization;
    private Org_info organization_info;
    private String id;
    private String fiscalName;
    private String searchKey;
    private String commercialName;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    private ArrayList<Locations> locations;

    public Cliente(Org_info organization_info, String client, String organization, String id, String fiscalName, String searchKey,String phone, String email,
            String commercialName,ArrayList<Locations> locations) {
        super();
        this.organization_info=organization_info;
        this.client = client;
        this.organization = organization;
        this.id = id;
        this.fiscalName = fiscalName;
        this.searchKey = searchKey;
        this.commercialName = commercialName;
        this.locations = locations;
    }
    //get and set method
```

How can I make the data class generic, and be able to store JSON data with the data node from both clients and providers, while receiving an array of data or a data object?

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    conection();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = br.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    String output = sb.toString();

    final Type tpEnvClient = new TypeToken<Data<Client>>(){}.getType();
    final Data<Client> envEmp = new Gson().fromJson(output, tpEnvClient);
```

When trying to store an array I get an error because I can't store a list of clients.

Comment: According to the duplicate, declaring `private final T data;` as `private final List<T> data;` should do the trick.

Comment: i change but i have this problem now ` Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $` , now i use `ArrayList<Data> la = new ArrayList<Data>();
   List<Client> list = new Gson().fromJson(output, la.getClass());`

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830699/how-parse-json-using-gson-when-object-is-either-jsonobject-or-jsonarray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make GSON accept single objects where it expects arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412261/make-gson-accept-single-objects-where-it-expects-arrays)